# This else runs even if the if was true

Tags: javascript, jquery

What this program its supposed to do is first with a range input you put how many elements you want to guess then it will show a random element form a json list and you have to guess the valnce and then it will load annother one and you continue. OK when i run this code everything is normal until you click submit button two times. When i click the submit botton the first time its goes well but the second time the program runs the if in the line 41 but it also runs the code in the else and if you submit more times it will run the alerts more and more times.
I have tried doing it other ways like just putting all into a for but it still runing code i dont want to.

```js
const $ = require('jquery');

let elementoActual;
let valorPositivoCorrecto;
let valorNegativoCorrecto;
let valorCuadroNegativo;
let valorCuadroPositivo;
// Button on click add the element
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#startButton").click(function() {
    $(".hide").hide();
    let questionHTML = '<div class="elementoQuimico"><img id="imgElemnt" src="" alt=""></div>' +
      '<div class="valenciasElemento">' +
      '<input type="text" class="valorPositivo" placeholder="Valencias positivas">' +
      '<input type="text" class="valorNegativo" placeholder="Valencias negativas">' +
      '</div>' +
      '<button class="submitButtonElement">SUBMIT</button>';
    $(".questions").append(questionHTML);
    putAnElement();
  }); //onclick ends
}) //ready ends

function putAnElement() {
  let numb = $("#textInput").val();
  let counter = 0;
  $.getJSON("../../json/valencias.json", function(data) {
    let numeroDeElemento = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
    elementoActual = data[numeroDeElemento];
    valorNegativoCorrecto = data[numeroDeElemento].valenciasNegativas;
    valorPositivoCorrecto = data[numeroDeElemento].valenciasPositivas;
    //$("#imgElemnt").attr( "src" , elementoActual.img);
    $("#imgElemnt").attr("alt", elementoActual.name);
    $("#imgElemnt").attr("width", "200px");
    $("#imgElemnt").attr("height", "200px");
    alert(numb);
    $(".submitButtonElement").click(function() {
      valorCuadroNegativo = $(".valorNegativo").val();
      valorCuadroPositivo = $(".valorPositivo").val();
      $(".valorNegativo").val("");
      $(".valorPositivo").val("");
      if (valorCuadroNegativo === valorNegativoCorrecto &&
        valorCuadroPositivo === valorPositivoCorrecto) {
        alert("correcto");
        counter++;
        alert(counter);
        if (counter != numb){
          putAnElement();
        } else {
          alert("ya");
        }
      } else {
        alert("incorrecto");
        counter++;
        alert(counter);
        if (counter != numb) {
          putAnElement();
        } else {
          alert("ya");
        }
      }

    });
  }); //getJSON ends

};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Tabla periodica</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/periodic-table.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="hide">
      <h1>TABLA PERIODICA</h1>
      <img src="../../img/tabla-valencias.png">
      <div class="buttons">
        <button id="startButton">EMPEZAR</button>
        <form id="submit-tabla">
          <label for="rangeInput"></label><input type="range" name="amountRange" id="rangeInput" min="10" max="30" value="20" oninput="this.form.amountInput.value=this.value" />
          <label for="textInput"></label><input type="number" name="amountInput" id="textInput" min="10" max="30" value="20" oninput="this.form.amountRange.value=this.value" />
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="questions">

    </div>
  </div>

  <footer>
    2017 &COPY; Nestor and Diego
  </footer>
  <script src="chemistry.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

And here is the json

```
[
    {
      "name":"hidrogeno",
      "valenciasNegativas":"-1",
      "valenciasPositivas":"1",
      "img":"img/Hidrogeno.svg"
    },
    {
      "name":"litio",
      "valenciasNegativas":"",
      "valenciasPositivas":"1",
      "img":"img/Litio.svg"
    },
    {
      "name":"sodio",
      "valenciasNegativas":"",
      "valenciasPositivas":"1",
      "img":"img/Sodio.svg"
    }
]
```

Comment: Please post only the relevant code, not the whole thing.

Comment: Every time your code calls `$(".submitButtonElement").click()` you register *another* "click" handler; the call does not remove the "click" handler that was already there.

Comment: Your JSON is returning `-1` and `1` in the `valenciasX` properties. Both of these values will coerce to true, hence the issue in the `if` statement. You need to either change the values to `0` and `1`, or better yet, use boolean values: `true` and `false`

Comment: Even without looking at *any* of the code, this comment: `*if you submit more times it will run the alerts more and more times*` says that you are adding event handlers inside other event handlers.  Add them up-front (with conditions if required).

Comment: I didn't read the whole code, but in theory, if statement wouldn't run both the if and else. Add a counter in the relevant places to help you find out when which function is being called. Most probably the code runs twice and calls both. Alternatively you can run it on debugger to check the same